# Can lift be lower for a model with higher AUC?

Tags: deep-learning, auc, model-evaluation, boosting

I am comparing a Deep neural net (using keras) and Xgboost on a dataset of around 3k observations with the ratio of 1's to 0's is 1:4. I am then using the models to predict on a test set and calculating the AUC and the max Lift (plotting the lift curve). For the DNN with tuned parameters the AUC (on test dataset) is 0.97 and the max lift is 32 whereas for the Xgboost the AUC (on test dataset) is 0.96 and the max lift is 38. Is it possible for a model with better AUC to have a lower lift?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for a model with better AUC to have a lower lift?

Based on the information you've presented, it would appear that the answer is "yes." The only reason it could be "no" is if you've made a programming error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your lift chart does not have to be linear. The lift can be significant(large slope) in some segments and almost no separation power in others. AUC and lift chart is not directly quantitatively related.